# "Default dictionary resource for language 'plnot found" error in jython while using a Morfologik library

Tags: nlp, jython, jython-2.5

I'm having quite a struggle trying to use Morfologik library in my project in jython. I need to use a PolishStemmer, so I imported *morfologik-polish*, *morfologik-stemming* and *morfologik-fsa* in jython console, using `sys.path.append`. However, each time I try to create a PolishStemmer object, the following situation occurs:

```
>>> p = PolishStemmer(PolishStemmer.DICTIONARY.COMBINED)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Default dictionary resource for language 'plnot found.
```

Now, according to the Morfologik API, this occurs only when the dictionary itself is not available. What additional .jars should I import to create and use PolishStemmer? *(Note: I already tried adding* `morfologik-tools-standalone`  *instead to the classpath, with no luck).*